# APKs not installing on Emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, apk

With the update of Android Studio 2.3, I've been having issues with my emulators. Eventually to "solve" the issue (`libwinthread-1.dll` being missing from the computer, supposedly) I've had to reinstall Android Studio 2.3.0 and create a new machine (A `nexus5x` running `Android 7 API 24`). That emulator works now (even though that error still displays), but now my project builds and installs, then doesn't launch. Fine, probably needs a good debugging sweep. I try to debug it in the emulator, and I get this error:

```
null
                com.android.ddmlib.ShellCommandUnresponsiveException
                at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.executeRemoteCommand(AdbHelper.java:504)
                at com.android.ddmlib.SplitApkInstaller.uploadApk(SplitApkInstaller.java:152)
                at com.android.ddmlib.SplitApkInstaller.install(SplitApkInstaller.java:78)
                at com.android.ddmlib.Device.installPackages(Device.java:904)
                at com.android.tools.idea.run.tasks.SplitApkDeployTask$SplitApkInstaller.installApp(SplitApkDeployTask.java:117)
                at com.android.tools.idea.run.RetryingInstaller.install(RetryingInstaller.java:86)
                at com.android.tools.idea.run.tasks.SplitApkDeployTask.perform(SplitApkDeployTask.java:86)
                at com.android.tools.idea.run.LaunchTaskRunner.run(LaunchTaskRunner.java:120)
                at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:635)
                at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$3.run(CoreProgressManager.java:170)
                at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIn... (show balloon)
```

And at this point I'm at a loss. I'm not sure if this is an issue with the manifest (Old project that carried over into this version of Android Studio) or if this is an issue with Gradle, but I'm not sure what to do with it.

The emulator is running a `Google APIs Intel x86 Atom 64 System Image` with `HAX` disabled (have to run it that way or the emulators don't run at all) if that helps.

Comment: Did you ever find out what the problem was?

Comment: Nah ;A; I forgot how I eventually got it to work, but I think I just reinstalled everything and made new emulators